# iOS 12 Apple Watch app - how to delete "available apps"?

Tags: watchos, ios, apple-watch

I have deleted the parent app from my iPhone running iOS12, but still see it's Apple watch app in the list of "available apps".

**How can I remove entries from the Apple Watch phone app under "available apps"?**